# Why does a cURL request from a PHP file not work, when the same cURL request from the Linux console does?

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to write small php code which has to make a curl call, but it hangs in between. Please find the code below:

```
$url = 'XXXXXX';
$curlHandler = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curlHandler, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curlHandler, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($curlHandler, CURLOPT_ENCODING, '');
curl_setopt($curlHandler, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
print var_dump(curl_error($curlHandler))."\n";
print curl_exec($curlHandler);
curl_close($curlHandler);
```

I am getting following output to this:

```
string(0) ""

"* About to connect() to XXXXXX port 80 (#0)"
"*   Trying 72.52.8.197... * connected"
"> GET XXXXXX HTTP/1.1"
Host: XXXXXX
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: deflate, gzip"
```

After this php process hangs.

While if I make curl request as follows, it works:

```
curl -v "XXXXXX"
* About to connect() to XXXXXX port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 72.52.8.197... connected
> GET XXXXXX HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Host: XXXXXX
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< Date: Tue, 04 Mar 2014 11:02:15 GMT
< Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
< Location: XXXXXX
< Pragma: no-cache
< Server: Apache
< Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=kkgmdajs0485tkjm2q7vrfl260; path=/; domain=.souq.com
< Set-Cookie: PLATEFORMC=sa; expires=Wed, 04-Mar-2015 11:02:15 GMT; path=/; domain=.souq.com
< Set-Cookie: PLATEFORML=ar; expires=Wed, 04-Mar-2015 11:02:15 GMT; path=/; domain=.souq.com
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Content-Length: 0
< Connection: keep-alive
< Set-Cookie: NSC_tpvr-83+63+9+208-91=ffffffff2d814a2945525d5f4f58455e445a4a423660;path=/;httponly
< 
* Connection #0 to host XXXXXX left intact
* Closing connection #0
```

Can someone explain me why there is difference in php curl call and unix curl call?

Comment: Are both requests done from _the same_ system?

Comment: Yes they are done from the same system

Comment: @PatomaS, please learn to speak valid English before you try to improve the English in a post or especially a title. I have rolled back your invalid edit, which should *never have been approved*.

Comment: @Sheridan Now that you mention it, would you be so kind to point me the errors in my correction so I can improve?. And before you get angry again, this is a sincere question.

Comment: @PatomaS, I'm sorry that you thought that I was angry before, or would become angry after reading your question, but that is untrue. I just try to uphold the high quality of posts that are expected on this great website and bad English in titles goes against that quality. You wrote *Why does a cURL request from a PHP file doesn't work, but the same cURL request from the Linux console does?* and that's simply *not* acceptable English. However, a small change could correct it: *Why does a cURL request from a PHP file not work, when the same cURL request from the Linux console does?*

Comment: If you try editing this post with that title, you shouldn't have any problems.

Comment: @Sheridan, I'll take your advice, and submit the change.

Comment: @Sheridan, I think you are a grammar-nazi... The title was perfectly understandable the first time, as it was a ridiculous tiny typo. This is a tech forum, not a grammar forum. Quality is in the solutions not in the past tense. I wonder how many languages you can actually speak apart from your mother tongue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command line curl call sets a User-Agent, but your PHP sample does not.

If I try the same request to that URL passing a user agent, it works fine.

Try adding one to your PHP code, e.g.:

```
curl_setopt($curlHandler, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,
    'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Iron/31.0.1700.0 Chrome/31.0.1700.0 Safari/537.36');
```

Some sites don't function properly if you don't specify a user agent or certain other http headers (like accept-language or accept), this one appears to be one of those sites.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I also just realised that I need to set user agent, in unix curl I was observing "curl/7.22.0 (i686-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3" as user agent and when I put in php, the php curl worked.

Answer (score 4):

The command line curl command has unescaped `&`s in them, they act as a "make it background task" marker and the numbers between the `[]`s are the identifier that bash assigns for them. They of course exit immediately since (for example) the `utm_campaign=desktop` is not a real command. You can read more in the [job control section](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/features_5.html) of bash's manual.

Just wrap your URL in `"`s on the command line, so the curl command receives the whole string:

```
curl "http://...."
     ^           ^
```

If you want to see the verbose messages (as seen in the php snippet), add the `-v` option before the URL.
For the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` you will need the [`-L`](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html#-L) option.

Comment: Hi my curl command succeeded even after adding -L option. I tried "curl -v -L "http://saudi.souq.com/sa-ar/apple-ipad-air-tablet-9-7-inch-16-gb-wifi-space-gray-6276310/i/?utm_source=vzr&utm_medium=cpt&utm_campaign=desktop&utm_content=71866954", and it succeeded without a fail. Please help me identify why same doesn't work in php.

Comment: @user1776860: Take a look at @drew010's answer, I've tried the php code snippet with the addded `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` and it seemed to work as expected. Without an user agent it just hangs. Looks like the other side wont accept a request without one (sending curl's own works too).